# How to boot USB from GNU GRUB 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1?

Tags: boot, grub2, usb, lvm

I am using HP 1000-notebook pc corei-3 series. I had installed Ubuntu 14.04.1-desktop-amd64, accidentally using the lvm option. After finding my 500 Gb hard drive stuck in lvm I started to find methods/GUI software to resize it. In the mean time my brother while trying to install windows 7 has deleted the lvm partition. Now I've nothing on my pc except GNU GRUB version 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1 command line. I've tried to reinstall Ubuntu using a bootable usb but it is not booting. Is there any command for booting usb from GNU GRUB which says, "Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions."

Answer (score 4):

This is a deep revive but since there is no answer, I may as well do it.

In GNU GRUB command line (hit c on menu) and type `ls -lh` in the shell and look for the hard drive that matches your USB by size...it should tell you that it found a partition on the USB.  Then do:

```
set root='hd[something],[some partition]'
chainloader +1
boot
```

It should then proceed to boot from your USB stick partition.