# I tried removing Ubuntu and now I can't boot into windows

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, grubrescue

I am brand new to all of this. I had a dual boot system going on. Everything was going pretty well for a while and I was really enjoying everything. I was having some serious issues and there didn't seem to be an easy fix. I decided to pretty much get rid of Ubuntu. Grub didn't like that and now I can't get back into windows. I need some help!

[image: image1]
[image: image2]

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to this:

[How to boot USB from GNU GRUB 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/521083/how-to-boot-usb-from-gnu-grub-2-02beta2-9ubuntu1/649190#649190)

It applies the same way except you want to be looking for your Windows partition (assuming you didn't accidentally wipe it).  Once back in Windows, you will need to change it so the bootloader won't kick into the GRUB menu every time you turn on your computer.  You should be able to find that with some google-ing.

Answer (score 0):

You removed important GRUB files and kernels. I would recommend you to get a Live CD/USB, format the Ubuntu partition and reinstall it. After the installation you will be able to access Windows. If you want, you can install EasyBCD (google about it) in Windows, recover your Windows bootloader and wipe Ubuntu.